# Контроль I/O для всего сервера

Tags: ubuntu, debian, centos, io, redhat

Я хочу контролировать IOPS для всего сервера. Могу ли ограничить IOPS до определённого значения? Определить очередь. Ставить процессы на паузу в случае превышения лимитов.

Comment: I/o дисковой подсистемы ?

Comment: Да, я думал использовать cgroup. Но пока не решил, как это сделать например для всех команд cp и mv

Comment: Гляньте тут https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git/ если нужен нормальный мониторинг - Netdata